What is causing the border of cgps being displayed like this?
The attached screenshot shows two SSH sessions to the same computer running Ubuntu 24.04LTS. On the left, I have connected running PuTTY and on the right I have connected using Windows Terminal.
In both screenshots, I've ran the same program called cgps.
As you can see, in PuTTY the border is drawn using random letters whereas in Windows Terminal it is drawn using proper lines. Why is that? I have tried several different fonts in PuTTY settings but it always ends up like this, so that's not the cause.


It seems to be an issue with terminal settings / encoding - setting the PuTTY Window -> Translation -> Remote character set to ISO-8859-1 and exporting TERM=vt100 or TERM=vt220 seems to "fix" it but I don't think that's the correct approach. Perhaps it's an issue with how cgps initializes ncurses?

Since both applications are on Windows, and one renders fine, I think it's a problem on the Windows end, so off topic here and should be posted on [su]

In PuTTY, under Window -> Translation, enable Enable VT100 line drawing even in UTF-8 mode:

